# sizeHint for a QTableView?

Tags: qt

I've got a `QWidget` containing a `QTableView`. The `QTableView` uses a subclassed `QStandardItemModel` as its model. When I add items to my model, the `QTableView`'s size hint remains fixed at `QSize(256, 192)`. Why isn't the size hint changing? When displayed, my `QWidget` does not have reasonable dimensions. Do I need to manually override the `sizeHint` method to get the functionality? Calling `updateGeometries` doesn't do anything, and google isn't finding any answers for me.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. `QTableView`'s sizeHint does not depend on its content by design.

Comment: I was talking to a coworker about this, and we realized the same thing. You didn't write this as an answer -- how should I resolve the question?

Comment: @amos write up an answer yourself, and give credit to comment by Pavel....I often do this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pavel answered this question in a comment above:

> This is the expected behavior. QTableView's sizeHint does not depend on its content by design.